# Gender Storage and data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a gender column

```
gender
```

Using MS SQL Server 2012

currently it is smallint which is 2 bytes -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)

and works like follows

```
1 = male
0 = female
-1 = not specified
```

we do a lot of queries on this type of field. and the issues I have are

1. Its not intuitive as to what the data means without explanation
2. It's using two bytes

so I was wondering how others do this

I could do a 1 byte char(1)

```
m = male
f = female
x = not specified
```

Would this cause any performance issues on where or join clauses.

Comment: In general, if your system is IO bound then the smaller your datatypes the better.

Comment: This depend on many things, especially your server implementation, which you didn't give.  The only reasonable way to find out is a test.  But I'd be surprised if you see a big difference.

Comment: use characters.  I don't like the female being equated to 0 and the male to 1... it seems off.  Characters are meaningful to anyone who looks at the data.  Don't forget you can use `null` too.

Comment: You could use bit, 1 for male, 0 for female and null for not specified...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175878/storing-sex-gender-in-database - related, if not a duplicate (doesn't get into performance specifics, certainly not on SQL 2012)

Comment: Seems like a bit of premature optimization.

Comment: Also, don't forget that, depending on who you ask, there are several more than 2 genders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (EHR software) store as a 1 byte char, as it is concise and easier to understand while working with lots of demographic data.

The possible values map as follows:

- `U` - unknown or unspecified
- `M` - male
- `F` - female
- `NULL` - person hasn't been asked/no value on record.

For us, it is important to note if they have purposely decided to not provide their gender, or if it hasn't been captured yet (thus `NULL` vs `U`).

One consideration is mapping this as a more meaningful structure in the application (like, an `enum` in .NET or similar). It's maybe a little annoying as an application guy to have to use a `switch` or other approach to get the enum, whereas I can cast an enum directly from an numeric value.

It's a trivial concern, of course, but if you're curious how was solved it, we used a `struct` type that could be coerced from a string (explicit conversion from string) and static constants to act as possible enum values.

Answer (score 3):

The much better way, in general, to do things list this is to use a domain or lookup table.

If your attribute is required, it should be non-nullable. If it is not-required, it should be nullable. `Null` means that the data is missing; the user didn't answer the question. It is a different value than an affirmative answer of "I don't know" or "None of your business." But I digress.

A schema like this is what you want:

```
create table dbo.person
(
  . . .
  gender_id tinyint null foreign key references dbo.gender(id) ,
  . . .
)

create table dbo.gender
(
  id          tinyint not null primary key clustered    ,
  description varchar(128) not null unique ,
)
insert dbo.gender values( 1 , 'Fale'   )
insert dbo.gender values( 2 , 'Memale' )
insert dbo.gender values( 3 , 'Prefer Not To Say' )
```

The domain of the column `gender_id` in the `person` table is enforced by the foreign key constraint and is

- `null` is missing or unknown data. No data was supplied.
- 1 indicates that the person is female.
- 2 indicates that the person is male.
- 3 indicates that the person didn't feel like giving you the information.

And, more importantly, when you need to expand the domain of values, like so:

```
insert dbo.gender values( 4 , 'Transgendered, male-to-female, post-gender reassignment surgery' )
insert dbo.gender values( 5 , 'Transgendered, male-to-female, receiving hormone therapy' )
insert dbo.gender values( 6 , 'Transgendered, female-to-male, post-gender reassignment surgery' )
insert dbo.gender values( 7 , 'Transgendered, female-to-male, receiving hormone therapy' )
```

Your code change [theoretically] consists of inserting a few rows into the domain table. User-interface controls, validators, etc., are (or should be) populating themselves from the domain table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it pretty much however you want, but if you like to follow standards, there is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218

```
The four codes specified in ISO/IEC 5218 are:
0 = not known,
1 = male,
2 = female,
9 = not applicable.
```