# Why is nodejs returning a smiley face on my BIT(1) row?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I was googling on how to store a `1` or `0` as a value. I chose the `BIT(1)` datatype: [image]

Then, for user authentication I store that value in a temporary `TEMPUSER` object like so inside `nodejs`: (`gender` a column in my `users` table)

```
db.query('SELECT * from users WHERE id = ' + db.escape(userID) + ' AND password = ' + db.escape(userPassword) + '', function(err, results) {
    TEMPUSER = {
        gender: results[0].gender
    }
});
```

Now, when I console.log `TEMPUSER` using:

```
console.log('Gender Data: ' +TEMPUSER.gender);
```

It displays:

[image]

How Bizarre? Shouldn't it be displaying `1` or `0`?

#### Edit:

And the gender row value is set to `1` as well in mysql for this specific user:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect if you did

```
console.log(typeof TEMPUSER.gender);
```

...you'd find it said `object`, because [the plugin you're using](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#type-casting) maps `BIT` columns to NodeJS `Buffer` objects. So you're getting a `Buffer` with one entry. The `+` in your `console.log` statement converts it to a string with one character, character code U+0001. On my Windows system, if I do:

```
console.log("\u0001");
```

...I get the smiley face, too.

Instead, use the buffer:

```
TEMPUSER = {
    gender: results[0].gender[0]
}
```

I'd check what you get when the query returns `NULL`; could be an empty buffer (the above would give you `undefined`), could be `null` (the above would give you an error).

Comment: Wow, totally forgot about the MYSQL node plugin. I keep putting nodejs under the bus for no reason.  Btw, I'm using the [felixge's](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) plugin if anyone else see's this thread. Would this be a bug in your opinion @T.J, or just normal behavior? Because I'll just use the `.charCodeAt(0)` method and be done with it. I just found it kind-of funny/odd a smiley face would pop up out of no where so randomly.. lol

Comment: @NiCkNewman: Following that link, it says it maps `BIT` to `Buffer`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was about to reply and tell you I had to use `toString()` haha. Quick edit TJ, did not know you could use the buffers like that. That's awesome. Just learned something about node that I never have before.  Love the `BIT` data type now. I was getting worried and thought I had to move to `tinyint` :(. Yep, this is now [solved](http://i.gyazo.com/2795aaa6784afa4fb3bc83a237fcbb79.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is really funny, should save that awkward behavior.

On a series note:

first, you should save boolean values with `tinyint` data type. (optionally, limit to one character.)

second, as deciding on data-type for gender, quick search result in this:

[Storing sex (gender) in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175878/storing-sex-gender-in-database)

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah it's either going to be `bit(1)` or `char(1)` for me. Using @T.J. Crowder's fix, I'd rather use bit as it's less bits than char.  Thanks for your insight ! ~ (And this matters to me when I have thousands if not hundred of thousands of characters)