# Vuejs radio buttons checked if v-model is an array

Tags: vue.js, radio-button, checked, v-for, v-model

How can i have checked radio button in v-for, if i my v-model is an array?

my data:

```
data() {
     return {
         persons: {
             name: [],
             surname: [],
             sex: [],
         }
     }
 }
```

and my radio:

```
<template v-for(person, person_index) in persons>
<div class="switch-sex">
   <input type="radio" name="sex" :id="'male'+person_index" value="male"
   v-model="persons.sex[person_index]">
   <label :for="'male' + person_index">M</label>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" :id="'female' + person_index" 
    value="female" v-model="persons.sex[person_index]">
   <label :for="'female' + person_index">F</label>
</div>
</template>
```

I need my first radio ( male) be checked in each person inside v-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your question and your objective, your doing dynamic forms for multiple persons then try like this

**Template**

```
 //n and index used for 0-based looping

 <div v-for="(n, index) in noOfPersons" :key="index">
     Person {{ index + 1 }}
     <div class="switch-sex">
        <input type="radio" :name="'sex'+(index+1)"  value="male" v-model="persons[index].sex">
        <label >Male {{index+1}}</label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <input type="radio" :name="'sex'+(index+1)" value="female" v-model="persons[index].sex">
        <label >Female {{index+1}} </label>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Script** (just an example to show its checked)

```
 data() {
    return {
        noOfPersons: 2,
        persons: [
            {name: '', surname: '', sex: 'male'},
            {name: '', surname: '', sex: 'female'},
        ]
    }
}
```

**For those using Vuetify.js** (it's different approach with `v-model` on the `v-radio-group` wrapper)

```
 <v-radio-group v-model="persons[index].sex" :mandatory="false">
     <v-radio label="Male" :value="1" color="blue"></v-radio>
     <v-radio label="Female" :value="0" color="blue"></v-radio>
 </v-radio-group>
```

Here's the [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBeOoy?editors=1010)

*NOTE. It is recommended to use `binary (0/1)` data like `0` for `male` or `1` for `female` or other numbers like `1/2` [Database Storage / ISO 5218](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175878/storing-sex-gender-in-database) or dummy variables. [Here's explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16689/why-is-gender-typically-coded-0-1-rather-than-1-2-for-example)*

Comment: Yeah, thank you, it's works. But how can i declare number of persons, if this number is dynamic and i can't declare "persons" like you, i have persons: []

Comment: It's just an example. What's your backend? you can consume API for example Laravel...you can assign its value thru axios...like `this.persons = response.data`

Comment: Then, `noOfPersons` will be `Object.keys(this.persons).length`.